# No indices match pattern "filebeat-*

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, kibana-5

I got error --- "No matching indices found: No indices match pattern "filebeat-*""
I just follow the tutorial on

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
curl -XGET 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'
{
"took" : 0,
"timedout" : false,
"shards" : {
"total" : 0,
"successful" : 0,
"skipped" : 0,
"failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
"total" : 0,
"max_score" : 0.0,
"hits" : [ ]
}
}
```

Need help...!!!!

Comment: Check that filebeat and logstash are started. If so configure the output to be file (in both of them) . The one that not writing to the file is the problematic one.

Comment: both filebeat and logstash were already started. i add the etc/logstash/conf.d/apache-01.conf also

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error i did not updated the filebeat.yml properly, if you have set the config to send to logstash update the file filebeat.yml with the following

open the filebeat.yml
$ sudo nano /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml

Comment the below lines 
#output.elasticsearch:
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

Uncomment the below lines

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]